# How do I compare strings in ReactNative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

im very new to reactNative development. and trying to compare two strings.

ex:
`response["Result"] equalsTo "True"`

i tried using `==` , `toEqual` but didnt work.

### Updated

im getting JSON Response like this

```
{ Result: true,
  Message: 'Login Success.',
  Code: 'Login Code' }
```

when i `console.log(response["Result"])` it prints `true`.

but when i compare. it always go to the else part.

```
if(response["Result"] == "true"){
    console.log("SUCCESS");
}else{
    console.log("ERROR");
}
```

Comment: react native is actually js,` ==` should be fine. Post more details how "didn't work"

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `==`?

Comment: i have updated the question @PedroCastilho

Comment: @aahung i have updated the question. im working with JSON Response

Comment: The problem here is that `true` is not the same as `"true"`.

Comment: damn... thats sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the value of `Response["Result"]` is `true`, not `"true"`. `true` is a [boolean constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Boolean_type), `"true"` is a string.

Change your code to:

```
if(response["Result"]){
    console.log("SUCCESS");
}else{
    console.log("ERROR");
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: got it. it worked. when im using native programming java or Objective C im treating it like string and then convert to boolean. but here its taking directly as boolean. Thanks